# Ordenar resultado de busca Magento

Tags: php, magento

estou precisando ordenar o resultado de busca dos produtos no magento por estoque, ou seja, quando procurar algum produto, preciso que mostre os que têm estoque para os que não tem estoque, obrigado.

Comment: Você vai ter que criar um modulo que vai substituir o search padrão do Magento.

Answer (score -1):

Galera, consegui resolver com esse plugin, segue o link:

[Link do Plugin para ordenar pelo estoque](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sort-products-automatically-sort-by-stock.html)